# Mal funcionamento do metodo Remover em posição definida na Lista dinâmica

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

O seguinte metodo realiza uma remoção de um elemento em uma posição pre-definida na classe de teste mas aparenta não estar funcionando mesmo não tendo erros de sintaxe e erros no teste feito pelo professor.

```
public void removerPosicao(int posicao){
    try {
        if(posicao == 0){
             removerPrimeiro();
        }else if(posicao == (getTamanho()-1)){
            removerUltimo();
        }else{
            Node aux = inicio;
            Node ant = aux;
            int posicao_atual = 0;
            while(posicao > posicao_atual){
                ant = aux;
                aux = aux.getProximo();
                posicao_atual++;
            }
            ant.setProximo(null);
            tamanho--;
        }    
    } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Erro:" + e + ". Inserir posicao valida !");
    }
}


@Test
public void testarRemoverPosicao(){
    iniciarLista();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){        
        lista.removerPosicao(1);
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }
}
```

Saída do terminal :

```
72 2 16 74
```

Saída esperada :

```
 72 2 16 74
 72 16 74 
 72 74
 72
```

(removendo sempre o elemento que fica na posição 1)

Comment: "Aparenta não estar funcionando". Por quê?

Comment: remover no inicio : 28 60 90 89 / 60 90 89 / 90 89 / 89  

remover no fim : 14 11 48 5 / 14 11 48 / 14 11 / 14 

remover na posição 1 : 72 2 16 74. Eh isso que aparece no terminal dos testes dos 3 métodos.

Comment: ele teria que diminuir a lista gradativamente igual aos outros 2 métodos removendo apenas o elemento q ficaria na posição 1 ? remover na posição 1 : 72 2 16 74 / 72 16  74 / 72 74 / 72.

Comment: Você pode postar o seu código completo de forma que ele seja compilável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difícil sem ver o código completo, mas por lógica a seguinte linha está errada:

```
ant.setProximo(null);
```

pois não apenas apaga a posição desejada, mas tambem o resto da lista. Nesse caso a saída deveria ser (e isso deveria constar na pergunta):

```
72 2 16 74
72
72
72
```

Para apagar um elemento de uma lista simplesmente encadeda, a linha acima deveria ser:

```
ant.setProximo(aux.getProximo());
```

ou seja, o elemento anterior ao que está sendo apagado (`ant`) deve apontar para o elemento seguinte ao elemento sendo apagado.

*(assumindo se tratar de uma lista simplesmente encadeada e que o resto do código está fazendo o que os nomes sugerem. Exemplo: `removerUltimo()` remove o último elemento, `setProximo()` seta o nó seguinte, ...)*